# Where to find Rudin's references.

Tags: reference-request

Principles of mathematical analysis(Rudin) comes with various references to proves and results that have appeared in several magazines such as A.m.s and Monthly Math, but I have entered these pages and I actually don't know how to look for the articles that the book quotes.

Comment: Try the dead-tree versions, your local university library should have them or be able to get them. I don't expect that all old articles have been converted.

Comment: Some of them are on jstor.org.  You may have to pay for a subscription if you can't get an account on a machine at a university that subscribes.  Alternatively there's the old-fashioned way: go to a university library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to JSTOR, MathSciNet, or other websites which contain compilations of journal articles you can log on with your university access if you are a student. If not, you can likely find a specific reference by searching for the title followed by "free pdf" or "pdf download". You can also sometimes find a reference by searching for the authors arXiv.org account or their university website where some professors post their papers free of charge.

Comment: Google scholar is also quite useful for this.